# Popup VBA macro dismiss

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32

I am running a VBA macro with pywin32 but when is finished I have a popup at screen, then if I don't click it can not continue executing my code. Any idea how to handle it?

My code:

````
def excel_vba(file):

    excel= win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    # Hacemos el excel visible para que no se quede en segundo plano
    excel.Visible = True
    # Abrimos nuestro archivo
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file)
    # Ejecucion de la macro
    excel.Application.Run('\'' + file + '\'' + "!Macro.Sheet.Button")

"""My code is stuck right here till I press the dialog box"""


    # Cerramos el COM Object
    wb.Save()
    excel.Application.Quit()
    del excel

file = "H:\Test.xls"
excel_vba(file)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution just change from visible to not visible this:

`excel.Visible = False`

Comment: yes, thats the way to do it. You can mark this answered